# Filtering / limiting Azure Search rest API to field with a specific value

Tags: rest, azure-cognitive-search

I have an azure search index which contains multiple types of entities.

If I do a search like `&search=term` it might return entities of multiple types, all containing the search value. How can I require a specific field to have a specific value? I tried with `&search=term&filter=my_field eq my_value` but that didn't work.

Alternatively I have to client-side filter the `value` array and filter out the specific entity-types I don't want, but I can't imagine this functionality doesn't exist in the query syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re sending queries to the Azure Search REST API using GET, you need to spell the parameter “$filter”, not “filter” (note the dollar sign). Otherwise the parameter will be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I search for a specific filename in Sharepoint using the Graph API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/" + driveId + "/root/search(q='name=thefilename.xls')");
```